# push docker's data directory using git

Tags: git, docker

I am using docker and django and postgress for a project. I followed this link here https://docs.docker.com/samples/django/ which basically saves the data from postgress in a directory under the main project like the following code:

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
```

This code works perfectly on my machine, but now I would like to push this project using git and so when the other party clones it, then can immediately run `docker-compose up` and continue where I left off with the same database intact (for example, the superuser in django should exist in the other machine). Is that possible? If yes, how can I achieve that?

I did some tests, but on my end it did not work, the other machine always showed some errors like directory is missing and when those were created, there were other errors like 'x is not a directory'.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
version: " # Your version"
volumes:
  pgdata: # empty definition uses volume defaults
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: pgdata # The named volume above
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
```

**Note:** One can inspect volumes by using `docker volume inspect` subcommand.